# Deleting a Foreign Key model?

Tags: django

I'm trying to delete a Foreign Key model, however after I delete it and try and save the model I get a ValueError:

*save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'orderassigned'.*

What I'm trying to achieve is delete the orderassigned Foreign Key model itself.

Below is this deletion code in views.py:

```
ordertocancel = Order.objects.get(orderid=orderid, orderassigned__user=self.request.user)
ordertocancel.orderassigned.delete() # This references a Foreign Key
ordertocancel.status = "ordered"
ordertocancel.save()
```

This is the Foreign Key:

```
orderassigned = models.ForeignKey('Assigned', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_DEFAULT, default=None)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It is not entirely celar what you aim to do here: delete the *reference* to that model object, or delete the `Assigned` record as well? Do you see the difference between the two?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I'm trying to delete the Assigned record itself which in turn should delete the reference to it as it will no longer exist

Comment: then you need to set the attribute to `None` as well, so after deleteing it `ordertocancel.orderassigned = None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting the OrderAssigned instance yet keeping it assigned to the instance of Order, you should make sure to assign it as null before saving like so:

```
ordertocancel = Order.objects.get(orderid=orderid, orderassigned__user=self.request.user)
order_assigned = ordertocancel.orderassigned
order_assigned.delete()
ordertocancel.orderassigned = None
ordertocancel.status = "ordered"
ordertocancel.save()
```

Comment: That makes a lof of sense, thank you! Much appreciated.